# Write a loop that sums the number of times that the words in wordList occur in the list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
count = 0
for word in newWordList:
    newWordList= word.count('theBells')
    count += 1
print(newWordList)
```

Comment: What's the question? This is just a dump of some code that does something, without any indication of what it does wrong, what it's supposed to do instead, etc.

Comment: friends can you help me when i run this code i am getting just zero i need some help because my list is really big. thanks in advance the code should be in 5 lines.

Comment: One pretty obvious problem is that you're reusing the name `newWordList` to mean two different things, some input list of words that we can't see, and a numeric count. That can't be a good idea.

Comment: so you want wordlist i have to count and sum the number i said in the top>

Comment: Meanwhile, you're just reassigning a new value to `newWordList` every time through the loop, so after the loop is over, you're going to get just `word.count('theBells')` for whichever `word` was last in the original list, while I assume you wanted something that uses the other words in some way. But since I don't know what that "something" is that you wanted, I don't know how to fix this, just that it's clearly wrong.

Comment: Finally, we need a complete example that we can run. We need to know what's in `newWordList`, what answer you're supposed to get and why you think you're supposed to get that, etc. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help.

Comment: the list is too long that's why its hard to post here.

Comment: Again, read the link I just gave you. We don't need the whole list in your real code, we need a _minimal_ example, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I interpret from the question in the title, and not much details, this is one way to do it. wordList is your source list to look up against and the inList is the input.

```
count = 0
wordList=["hello","hi","is","and", "are", "you"]

#'are' appears twice and 'you' once - total should be 3
inList=["how", "are","you", "where", "are", "your", "friends" ]
count = 0
#count number of times the words in wordList appear in the input list 'inList'
for word in inList:
    if word in wordList:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

**output:**

```
3
```

Comment: but i need 5 line of code is there any thing can be added if yes please explain and write the statement that would be really help ful thanks in advance.